# Picard group of a conic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, line-bundles

Suppose $C$ is a smooth conic in $\mathbb{P^2}$, that is, $C$ is a hypersurface of degree two in the projective plane.

Assume that the base field is complex numbers. By the genus degree formula, we can check that the genus of $C$ is zero, so $C$ is isomorphic to a $\mathbb{P}^1$. So the Picard group of $C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

My question:

Is this generated by $O_C(1)$?

This $O_C(1)$ is degree 2 line bundle on $C$ I suppose. If this is the generator, then it seems to mean there are no degree one divisors on $C$. This seems very strange. I think I am
going wrong somewhere. Can anyone point this out? Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you said - $\mathcal{O}_C(1)$ is a degree 2 line bundle on $C$ and hence does not generate the Picard group!

Comment: @loch, Then what is the generator of the picard group? Since the Picard group is cyclic, it has to be a square root of $O_C(1)$ right?

Comment: Your $C$ is a $\mathbb{P}^1$, so the usual $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ is the generator of the Picard group. 

The point is that the induced map $Pic(\mathbb{P}^2) \rightarrow Pic(C)$ is not surjective.